# Is Sylius still support createNew() methods?

Tags: sylius

Is Sylius still support createNew() methods?

For example creating new products should work using product repository:

```
    $repository = $this->container->get('sylius.repository.product');

    $product = $repository->createNew();
```

Currently i have an error
"Undefined method 'createNew'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!"
when im trying to createNew any product or taxon.

Should it work or methods was changed?

Answer (score 1):

Solution from Sylius github, service was changed to sylius.factory.product
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/4217